# How to create predefined restApi resource? with explicit name

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam

Below is the SAM template that tries giving explicit name(`some_name`) to restApi resource on AWS:

```
  SampleApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: some_name
```

---

But I see the events in stack creation as:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::1111222333344:assumed-role/some-role/i-34454503ea88 
is not authorized to perform: 
apigateway:DELETE on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/vxrf0gfs2a
```

where `vxrf0gfs2a` is the random name of restApi

Cloudformation stack creates Api gateway with explicit name `some_name`, but we . would like to have `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/vxrf0gfs2a` with some explicit name `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/some_explicit_name`

---

How to give explicit name to `AWS::Serveless:Api`'s `restapis` resource?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, just as you can't choose your EC2 instance id. It may be helpful to understand why you want an explicit name, so we can describe how to achieve the end goal without being able to name the API instance explicitly. If you want an externally friendly name, you can use Custom Domain Name. If you want to be able to reference the arn easily, you can already do that within the same template, or export the arn.

If you're trying to solve the problem "is not authorized to perform: 
apigateway:DELETE " please indicate that as well.

Comment: @TheClassic we have multiple test environments.. we want to name those test environment for each api gateway's restapi

Comment: I recommend keep doing what you're doing, name the API as you are. If you need a predefined name to call the APIs, use a custom domain name.